# What is this coupler for?

Tags: ethernet

Someone asked me if they could split an Ethernet connection with this device. Obviously, it won't work. As far as I know, since Ethernet 10/100 uses dedicated transmit/receive pairs, it shouldn't work with both devices connected. Also not Gigabit since that needs one master and one slave. Someone still designed and is manufacturing these. What is this thing good for?

[image: cursed RJ45 connector thing]

Answer (score 3):

It's a three-way T-type 8P8C coupler. That is nothing you can use with Ethernet, unless you keep disconnecting one device. You could use it with POTS or ISDN S<sub>0</sub>.

For Ethernet cable sharing up to 100 Mbit/s (10BASE-T and 100BASE-TX) you'd need a pair of matching adapters moving the unused pairs 4-5 and 7-8 over to the secondary's 1-2 and 3-6:

[image]

For 1000BASE-T (and faster) you do need a switch.